# Tomcat installation is not working on fedora 15

Tags: linux, tomcat, installation

I am trying to install tomcat on my machine(`Linux Fedora 15`).

I have followed the below steps

1. I have entered in to root and typed the following

   ```
   [root@user ~]# tomcat

   bash: tomcat: command not found...

   Install package 'tomcat' to provide command 'tomcat'? [N/y]
   ```

   I have entered `y` and result is installed tomcat on machine as below

   ```
    * Running... 
    * Resolving dependencies...
   ```
2. Typed the command tomcat to check whether installed or not as below

   ```
   [root@user ~]# tomcat
   Usage: /usr/sbin/tomcat {start|start-security|stop|version}
   ```

   From the above we can confirm that tomcat has been installed right?
3. Tried to check which tomcat and where is it located as below

   ```
   [root@user ~]# which tomcat
   /usr/sbin/tomcat
   [root@user ~]# whereis tomcat
   tomcat: /usr/sbin/tomcat /etc/tomcat /usr/share/tomcat
   ```
4. Tried to start the tomcat server as below

   ```
   [root@user ~]# /usr/sbin/tomcat start
   /usr/sbin/tomcat: line 30: /logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
   ```

So whats wrong here and why the tomcat server is unable to start ? whether need to check/set any other addition settings for starting tomcat ?

Also I tried like below

```
[root@user ~]# /etc/init.d/tomcat start
Starting tomcat:                                           [  OK  ]
```

Here i hope it indicates the tomcat has started and hence opened the browser and typed `localhost:8080` but the result is

```
Oops! This link appears to be broken.
Did you mean: localhost-­8080.­com
--------
--------
```

So why I am unable to start the server and view it on browser?  Can any one please let me know the procedure to start the `tomcat` server

Comment: Did you try to access by http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: yup i tried and still the same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the broken logging configuration is covered in this [article](http://caffiendfrog.blogspot.de/2011/02/tomcat-6-fedora-14-frustrations.html)

In short:

1. edit `/usr/sbin/tomcat6`
2. remove the comments avoiding the load of `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf`

But I think more of the configuration is not in a good state.

Generally check the version of your tomcat6 package.
I'm suspecting that it is outdated.

See [Tomcat6 Changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/changelog.html) - current version is *6.0.36*.
So check if you can get a more recent package or better - install it manually from the [tomcat download page](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi).